# Can not click on controls MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, input

I manually placed the following code in the _Layout.cshtml

```
@model AssignmentTrialMVC.Models.Search
<div id="loginStrip">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <span style="border-right: 1px solid white; padding-right: 5px;">
            <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Logout", "User")
        </span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span style="border-right: 1px solid white; padding-right: 5px;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "User")
        </span>
        <span style="padding-left: 5px;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "User")
        </span>
    }
</div>
<div id="searchCell">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.brand)
        <input id="searchSubmitButton" type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
    }
</div>
```

I can view the controls in the screen but I **can not** click on the controls, but using tab I can focus the controls.

Please help me with this.

Comment: which control you cannot click?

Comment: textbox and button. I can not place the cursor on the text box by clicking and also can't click the button

Comment: means you cannot write in textbox?

Comment: and submit button not clickable????

Comment: i updated my last comment

Comment: any jquery plugins in your project>

Comment: Yes I created a basic MVC application it automatically adds

Comment: thats weird its strange

Comment: yes, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: try ctrl+f5 referesh your page and see

Comment: I found the solution myself, `z-index: +1000;` in CSS for the division did the trick. Can you say me how to add styles to text box added using `@Html.TextBoxFor()`

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.brand, new {@style="z-index:99999;"})

Comment: you can simply set z-index for div loginStrip

Comment: How can I do the styling externally

Comment: what you mean by externally??

Comment: a separate file for CSS and I can't add a place holder too

Comment: Try like this:
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.brand, new {id="css-id", @class="css-class-name"})

Comment: use you content->css->style.css file to add external css.

Comment: Why do you have model in  your _Layout page? it shouldn't be there, remove it and simply remove TextBoxFor and see if the problem is solved or not

Comment: I had this same problem, but not with MVC.  Turns out I had a transparent div covering it.  Inside the div was a panel that I made visible and invisible, but when that was gone, the div was still there.  Couldn't figure it out because a dropdown list was still clickable, but the text boxes and button wasn't.  But that invisible div didn't cover the dropdown.Seeing the z-index comment which solved the problem tipped me off.     Just adding this in case it helps anyone.